# how to bind id at <li> with event Onclick

Tags: javascript, ajax

Good day all, I little stuck how to bind value `id` at `<li>` tag

My ajax

```
//AJAX MENGAMBIL KATEGORI SEKOLAH
$.getJSON('http://localhost/aplikasi/assets/www/include/kategori.php', function(data) {
    console.log(data); //Untuk melihat data yang berhasil diambil di firebugs
    results = data.items; //Menampung array ke dalam variabel results

    //menggunakan fungsi each untuk membuat elemen list, sesuai banyaknya array
    $.each(results, function (index, kategori) {
        var html;

        //Membuat element list untuk setiap kategori
        html = '<li id="klik" data-katid="';
        html += kategori.kat_id;
        html += '"><a id="klik2" data-transition="slide" href="#list" OnClick="carisekolah()">';
        html += kategori.kat_nama; 
        html += '</a></li>';

        //Memasukkan ke dalam unordered list        
        $('#kategorisekolah').append(html);
    });

    //Refresh list
    $('#kategorisekolah').listview('refresh');

    //Memberikan fungsi ke setiap element 
    $("#listsekolah").children("li").bind("click", function (e) {
        carisekolah($(this).attr("data-katid"));
    });

});

function carisekolah(id) {
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/aplikasi/assets/www/include/list.php?id=' + id, function(data) {
        console.log(data); //Untuk melihat data yang berhasil diambil di firebugs
        results = data.items; //Menampung array ke dalam variabel results
        $('#listsekolah').empty();
        //menggunakan fungsi each untuk membuat elemen list, sesuai banyaknya array
        $.each(results, function (index, sekolah) {
            var html;

            //Membuat element list untuk setiap sekolah
            html = '<li data-sekid="' + sekolah.content_id + '">';
            html += '<h2>' + sekolah.content_nama + '</h2>'; 
            html += '<p>' + sekolah.content_alamat + '</p>'; 
            html += '<p> Telepon : ' + sekolah.content_telepon + '</p>'; 
            html += '</li>';


            //Memasukkan ke dalam unordered list        
            $('#listsekolah').append(html);
        });

        //Refresh list
        $('#listsekolah').listview('refresh');

    });
}
```

My HTML

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Aplikasi Pencarian Sekolah</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <p> Selamat datang di aplikasi pencarian sekolah..<br /><br />
            Silahkan memilih kota..
        </p>
        <a href="#kategori" data-role="button" data-inset="true"> JABODETABEK </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="kategori">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Aplikasi Pencarian Sekolah</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="kategorisekolah" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="list" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Kembali">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>List Sekolah</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <!-- Format list Jquery Mobile menggunakan fitur 'Pencarian' -->
        <ul id="listsekolah" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Cari sekolah..." data-inset="true"></ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

I tested with static id and it works

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/aplikasi/assets/www/include/list.php?id=1'
```

My function carisekolah(id) with get that parameter id is totaly fail, How i can get the paramater id in the right ways?

Comment: Show your HTML please.

Comment: I already add it sir, sorry before

Comment: @DonnyAgus -- I dont see any children for your UL, are these LI's being added dynamically?

Comment: nah, thats fail function and  i already delete it, i dont need to bind it, i just making a event onclick function thx bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand your question. But it sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
$("li").on("click", function(event){ 
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    carisekolah(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem's like you are binding the `<li>` of your list at DOM ready, however in your HTML markup your list has no children. If these are being added dynamically, then you should use event delegation. Give this a try:

```
$(document).on('click', '#listsekolah li', function() {
    carisekolah(this.id);
});
```

If the ID is actually coming from the `data-katid` attribute, call the function like this:

```
carisekolah($(this).data("katid"));
```